# Make a div half the width of another div

Tags: javascript, css

What i'm trying to do is make the title of a blog post exactly half the width of the blog description and align itself at 50% of the width of the blog description.

This is what i tried in JS:

`var post_title_width = document.getElementById("post_desciption").offsetWidth;`

`var post_title_width = post_description * 0.5; 
document.getElementbyId("post_title").style.width = post_title_width;`

HTML:

```
    <div class="post">
    <span class="post_title">This is a test title, testing some javascript...........</span><br>
    <span class="post_description">Hello this is a test description right here, just to test some code im trying to do</span>   
    </div>
```

I am not using css because i want to test javascript and learn how to use it efficiently.

Comment: Any specific reason for not using css?

Comment: You should also provide an html fragment showing how these are related/nested.

Comment: Try rounding it and adding a unit: `document.getElementbyId("post_title").style.width = (post_title_width | 0) + 'px';`

Comment: This is really a job for CSS, you can do it in javascript but it will be painful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/LfnYj/)):

HTML

```
<div id="head"><div id="half"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
#head {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
}
#half {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("half").style.width = document.getElementById("head").offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
```

JS for margin inner block at the center of it's countainer try to use this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/LfnYj/2/)):

```
document.getElementById("half").style.marginLeft = (document.getElementById("head").offsetWidth - document.getElementById("half").offsetWidth) / 2 + 'px';
```

Comment: Great! Now how would i align the title (#half) at the 50% width of the description, practically text-align: centre;, but aligning it in terms of the width of the description (#head)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it in javascript, you've got a few problems:

1. You're trying to target class names with getElementbyId
2. Your variable names are messed up
3. Spans are not block elements, so setting the width isn't applicable unless you set overflow and change the display to block or inline-block

http://jsfiddle.net/cmweU/

```
var post_description = document.getElementsByClassName("post_description")[0],
    post_description_width = post_description.offsetWidth,
    post_title_width = ( post_description_width * 0.5 ) + "px"; 

document.getElementsByClassName("post_title")[0].style.width = post_title_width;
```